# How to fix incorrect syntax near ' '?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, code-behind

Hello I'm having a problem with my query in this code I want to query a specific data rows where 'CourseNo' = 'CmpE 513';

```
   string getText = this.SubjectList.Value;

    //Connection String
    connector.ConnectionString = "Data Source=keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True";

    query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = " + getText + "";

    SubjectlistData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);
    SubjectlistTable = SubjectlistData.Tables[0];
```

The Error says incorrect syntax near '513'

The result displays as an int not a string.

In my sql server query I tried this:

```
select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where courseno = 'CmpE 513';
```

And the result displays a data.

How do I add a quotation (' ') in my aspx code behind in my string getText?

I tried:

```
string getText = this.SubjectList.Value;
query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = " + 'getText' + "";
```

But I get an error, How do I fix this?

Comment: courseno field table structure int and nvarchar?

Comment: no the courseno datatype is varchar.

Comment: Consider looking into using parameters instead; this code is possibly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, I will revise my code later. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your select query looks like

```
query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = " + getText + "";
```

**Problem**

In above case if **getText** is of type **int** then no doubt above query will work but in your case it's a string thus there a problem if not enclosed within **quotation**, like you are facing as it terminates the line at whitespace and rest of the charaters are not recognized to **sql compiler**.

```
string getText = this.SubjectList.Value;
query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime, EndTime,Room, Instructor, Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = " + 'getText' + "";
```

**Problem**

In above case you are trying to enclose **getText** in incorrect way this ain't the correct way to enclose a string object on doing so it will either become a string rather than string object or will result in compile time error.

**Solution**

You need to enclose your **getText** and make it a string

```
query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = '" + getText + "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

As "CmpE 513" contains a whitespace, it should be enclosed by single quotes

Like suprabhat suggested use the following code:

```
query = "select CourseNo,CourseDescription,Units,Day,StartTime,EndTime,Room,Instructor,Amount,Status from assessmentform where CourseNo = '" + getText + "'";
```

Comment: One question though, That subjectlist is a select tag id. But when it displays the result it doesn't display the selected option that I click, it will only display the first selected option in my code. Example: the default selected option of the select tag is "CmpE 513", but when I go to select the "CmpE 516" dropdownlist and click proceed. The "CmpE 516" did not display but only "CmpE 513".

Comment: Just before executing the query statement.
Use the following code "MessageBox.Show(query);" to make sure you're executing the right query.
Also try executing the same query on your database and compare the result. They both should be same.